# Segmentation Fault on Last Iteration

Tags: c

I am trying to randomly fill a 2d array with values then multiply them, but for some odd reason when I run my code, on the last iteration, I get a segmentation fault. I have tried decreasing the number I am passing it and everything, but the fault still persists. Here is the code I am trying to execute, any help is much appreciated, thanks.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 

    FILE *matrixFile;
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);  // the number of matrices
    int i, j;   // must declare outside of for loop due to resolve C99 mode error
    double arrA[n][n];// = CreateRandomMatrix(n);
    double arrB[n][n];
    double sumArr[n][n];
    matrixFile  = fopen("home/acolwell/Documents/CPE631_HW2_Number1/results.txt", "w+");

    printf("Usage: %s <size of nxn matrices>\n", argv[1]);

   // randomly populate arrA and arrB
   for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       printf("%d\n", i);
       for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
       {
           printf("%4d", j);
           arrA[i][j] = (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
           arrB[i][j] = (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
       }
    }

    printf("Exiting Matrix randomization");

    // multiply the matrices and write them to the file
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            sumArr[i][j] = arrA[i][j] * arrB[i][j];
            printf("Writing matrix ");
            fprintf(matrixFile, "%0.3lf\n", sumArr[i][j]);
        }
    }

    if(matrixFile)
    {
        fclose(matrixFile);
    }

    matrixFile = NULL;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, in C you can't use a non-constant value when creating an array.

Comment: @cdonts Yes, you can. It's called a `VLA` [variable length array] and has been supported since c99, IIRC

Comment: @CraigEstey Good to know!

Comment: How large is `n`? If it's large enough, you'll generate a stack overflow because the default stack size under most systems is ~8MB. (i.e.) if `n` is greater than 490, it's trouble ...

Comment: You don't do any error checking from your `fopen()`.  I would at least check the return value.  The point of @CraigEstey is good, you shouldn't allocate something like this on the stack.  Use the heap (malloc/free).

Comment: Off topic: the element-wise multiplication you are doing here is not "multiplying the matrices". For matrix multiplication you need a further nested loop computing `sumArr[i][j] = arrA[1][j]*arrB[i][1]+arrA[2][j]*arrB[i][2]+...+arrA[n][j]*arrB[i][n]`

Comment: Can you please give some condition (such as the matrix size, command line parameter `argv[1]`) that generates your segfault.  I can't reproduce it.  (Although the `printf("Writing matrix ");` inside the loop is annoying.)

Comment: @e0k I fiddled with it a bit here. Try `5000`--sure to fail [didn't binary search the exact number]. I've isolated the fault to _any_ line that follows the VLA definitions. In OP code, that's the `fopen` [purely because stack already bad]. But, if `fopen` goes above VLAs, fault is `printf` for usage.

Comment: @CraigEstey That's the problem then, it's too big for the stack.  He just needs to rewrite it to use the heap instead.  I would write a correction, but you figured that part out and should get credit for it.

Comment: @e0k Thanks. I've posted an answer. If you thought simple `VLA`s were interesting ...

Comment: @CraigEstey It seems his real problem was the file name... oh well.  It's worth knowing about that limit of use VLAs.

Comment: @e0k I saw the lack of full path, but didn't want to be pedantic about it, particularly since there was already an answer from Mike about it. Oh, well, if OP decides to "crank up the juice" with larger arrays, he's already covered, so maybe still useful [and I had fun doping out the syntax for the `docalc` method]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is going to come down to writing off the end of your array or failure to open your file. I would suggest running gdb to check out your program when it is running, but from a quick glance I wonder if you don't mean to have

```
"/home/acolwell/Documents/CPE631_HW2_Number1/results.txt"
```

as the file to write instead of

```
"home/acolwell/Documents/CPE631_HW2_Number1/results.txt"
```

I would suggest checking the result of your fopen call before calling fprintf.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes it just takes an extra set of eyes......I feel pretty bad now that it was something so simple.

Comment: It usually is and an extra set of eyes or trying to explain it to someone is usually what it takes to find it. It happens to all of us.

Answer (score 1):

If `n` is large enough, you'll generate a stack overflow using `VLA`s. I've verified this experimentally with your code (e.g. use `n` of 5000).

So, you'll need to use `malloc` to allocate from heap. But, that would require a bit of a rewrite.

Here's a way to use heap allocation *and* get the benefit of a `VLA` [using some slight trickery]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define C(_arr) (double (*)[(size_t)(n)]) _arr

void
docalc(FILE *fout,int n,double arrA[n][n],double arrB[n][n],double sumArr[n][n])
{
    // must declare outside of for loop due to resolve C99 mode error
    int i,
     j;

    // randomly populate arrA and arrB
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%4d", j);
            arrA[i][j] = (double) rand() / (double) RAND_MAX;
            arrB[i][j] = (double) rand() / (double) RAND_MAX;
        }
    }

    printf("Exiting Matrix randomization");

    // multiply the matrices and write them to the file
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            sumArr[i][j] = arrA[i][j] * arrB[i][j];
            printf("Writing matrix\n");
            fprintf(fout, "%0.3lf\n", sumArr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    FILE *matrixFile;
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);              // the number of matrices

    printf("Usage: %s <size of nxn matrices>\n", argv[1]);

    matrixFile = fopen("/tmp/results.txt", "w+");
    if (matrixFile == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1);
    }

    double *arrA = malloc(sizeof(double) * n * n);
    double *arrB = malloc(sizeof(double) * n * n);
    double *sumArr = malloc(sizeof(double) * n * n);

    docalc(matrixFile,n,C(arrA),C(arrB),C(sumArr));

    if (matrixFile)
        fclose(matrixFile);

    matrixFile = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What?! no `free()`'s? Blasphemy!

Comment: @e0k Yeah, and I didn't check `malloc` for `NULL`, either. So [egads!], double blasphemy ... :-) For me, I generally don't do `free` from `main` because it's a bit of a moot point as the program will terminate immediately [and it's actually faster to _not_ do them--a special case]. If I were doing the `malloc` inside a library function [that called `docalc`], I _would_ do the `free`

Answer (score 0):

I just compiled and tested your code. The file name you are giving is incorrect; you need a "/" in front of "home".

Not sure what the requirements are, but write your matrixFile like a matrix: add a new line after *each row* of the matrix is "multiplied", not after every element:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
         sumArr[i][j] = arrA[i][j] * arrB[i][j];
         printf("Writing matrix ");
         fprintf(matrixFile, "%0.3lf ", sumArr[i][j]);
     }
     fprintf(matrixFile, "\n"); 
}
```

Also, take Craig Easley's comment seriously. Stack Overflow can happen, even off the premises this website ;) Consider allocating your matrix dynamically on the heap.